# Is it possible to pause and resume like event when scrolling webpage using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I using selennium with python to crawl webpage. But I want to pause and resume everytime when scrolling webpage. Is it possible?

Comment: Use Explicit Wait while scrolling.It would better if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an explicit wait or poll for certain elements every time you scroll. I would be interested to know if you are dealing with some lazy loading, where the elements you are looking for are not already in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you but that's not exactly what I want. Assume I'm scrolling or action on the webpage and I stop to sign in to the web, how can I do that? I try to close this tab and open another tab but it's not optimized.